# Linear transformation restricted a specific subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ and let $W = \ker(T-\lambda I)^m \subset V$ be a subspace of $V$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with algebraic multiplicity $m$. I suspect that the restriction of $T$ to $W$ is $(T-\lambda I)$ i.e for all $w \in W$ we have $T\mid_{W}(w) = (T-\lambda I)(w) = Tw - \lambda w$.

But I can't show if it's actually true. Is it? If so, can someone please show me a proof for this?

Here's why I'm suspecting about that... if this is true, then it'll follow that $(T-\lambda I)^m$ is nilpotent, and at the moment that's good for me because with this I can keep understanding the proof of Jordan Canonical Form.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ agrees with $T-\lambda I$ on $W$, then $0=-\lambda I$ on $W$. Since $W$ contains at least an eigenspace of $T$, it is not the zero subspace. Therefore $\lambda$ is necessarily zero. It follows that the statement in question isn't true when $\lambda\ne0$. For instance, suppose $T$ is the identity map on a non-trivial vector space $V$. The eigenvalue $1$ has multiplicity $m=\dim V$ and hence $W=\ker(T-I)^m=\ker(0)=V$, but $T|_W=T|_V=T\ne 0=T-I$.

Comment: That makes sense... How can I prove then that $T \mid_W$ is nilpotent?